# How do I link an "onClick" event to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have a button with an `onclick` event.

My javascript for the button is not in the HTML document, but I linked it to the document with `<script src="example.js"></script>`. How do I make the "onclick" event link to my javascript file? This is what I tried.

```
function pasuser(form) {
    if (form.id.value=="user") { 
        if (form.pass.value=="password") {              
            location="example.html" 
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Password")
        }
    } else {
            alert("Invalid UserID")
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NATUREBOWL- LOGIN</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/> 

    <script src="loginform.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <p>Log in to Conitinue</p>
        <form name="login"><p>username    </p><input name="id" type="text">
            <br/>
        <p>password</p>
        <input name="pass" type="password">
            <center>
                <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="login.js">
            </center>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS-** The `function pasuser(form)`code is login.js.

**PPS-** Sorry if my question is a little vague, I had trouble describing it. Just tell me and I can clear up something or delete this question.

Comment: You are passing wrong name in onclick. It should be onclick="pauser('login');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External code linked with a `<script src=""/>` tag behaves just like the code you put directly inside `<script></script>` tags. So treat your function `pasuser(form)` just as if it was directly coded in the HTML.

OnClick and the other event properties want javascript code inside their quotes, therefore specifying a file name `onClick="login.js"` is absolutely not correct. You have to put inside there some javascript code which calls your function, passing the form as argument: `onClick="pasuser(document.forms.login)"`

Be aware, though, that your code has many weaknesses and bad design issues:

1. Nowdays, accessing forms and form elements by name is a bit of an old practice
2. Having an element named "id" can lead to ambiguity inside the DOM tree
3. You should never, ever, never, have such an username/password verification on client side code! Ever!

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of that, but it did work! Also, don't worry about the security of the code. I will not be using this method on the real website. I was just doing this as practice in java script :)

Answer (score 1):

onClick can't redirect you to another page.It is not designed that way. All you have to do is include your .js file in the header section in html document . It will include the .js page to the current html document. You have to ask for your desired function which will be triggered when the button is clicked

```
<head>
   <script src="loginform.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can attach any function from this .js file to your button's onClick envent

```
onClick="pasuser(//parameters);"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import your .js file, actually is like writing that code in the page itself. Just call the function name in the `onclick` specification.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the onclick to login.js, make sure the .click value is set to the name of the function, so your onclick should be

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="pasuser(< put parameter here )">
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want the onclick to call that function.

```html
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="pasuser(<parameters>)">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the OnClick requires the function to be run. Just linking the file isn't enough because your browser doesn't know that you want it to run the function. Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="pasuser(form)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well what you have to do is to call the function not the js.
so the code should look like this

```
<center>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="pasuser(form)">
</center>
```